# PyQt6: Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'unload'

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

I am trying to make a very simple web browser with PyQt6 and its widgets. I am just trying to display DuckDuckGo as the main search engine. The problem is the following: the main window works perfectly, however it does not load the DuckDuckGo page, along the following console output: `js: Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'unload'.`.

I searched through PyQt6 docs and similar questions in stackOverflow. However, nothing of that worked. I still do not understand what does this error mean, although I tried to search information about it. The code is the following:

```
#importing PyQt6 and dependencies
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
import sys

#Main Window Class
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self): #Constructor
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(300,300) #Size
        self.setWindowTitle("Web Browser") #Title

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(main_layout) #Not used

        self.showMaximized() #Max window 

    def webSearchEngine(self): #Set DuckDuckGo as main browser 
        self.web = QWebEngineView()
        self.mainSearchEngine = QUrl("https://duckduckgo.com") #Display Url
        self.web.load(self.mainSearchEngine)
        
        

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = Window()
window.show() #Initiate window
window.webSearchEngine() #Initiate DuckDuckGo (Not working)
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. 'js: Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'interest-cohort'' is related to the Permissions-Policy header used by the web page I am trying to load, not the Python code I provided.

This error is related to the "Interest Cohort" feature, which is a part of Google's FLoC ([Federated Learning of Cohorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_Learning_of_Cohorts)) initiative, but it requires explicit permission to be enabled.

Although I found out that this is not the main reason it is causing that DuckDuckGo isn't poping out, I researched and it seems that just by only ignoring this error it should all be fine.

The reason why my search engine wasn't poping up is because I forgot to add it to the main layout, so I did the following thing:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
import sys

#Main Window Class
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self): #Constructor
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(300,300) #Size
        self.setWindowTitle("Web Browser") #Title

        global main_layout
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(main_layout) #Not used

        self.showMaximized() #Max window 
    
    def on_load_finished(self,ok):
        if ok:
            print("Everything going ok")
        else:
            print("An error has occurred")


    def webSearchEngine(self): #Set DuckDuckGo as main browser 
        self.web = QWebEngineView()
        self.mainSearchEngine = QUrl("https://duckduckgo.com") #Display Url
        self.web.load(self.mainSearchEngine)
        self.web.loadFinished.connect(self.on_load_finished)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.web)
        
        

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = Window()
window.show() #Initiate window
window.webSearchEngine() #Initiate DuckDuckGo (Not working)
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

First of all, I created a 'def on_load_finished()' function that checks out if DuckDuckGo was loading even if I was not seeing on my python window. And it was returning me good values, so I figured out that I was forgetting to add the web widget to the main layout.

So, just by declaring 'main_layout' as a global variable and then using the 'addWidget()' function to include the web widget, it worked all fine.

[image: Screenshot]